# How do I Programatically close ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

Got a ContextMenu which pops up with some controls inside:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddFolderName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="Create here"
            Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</ContextMenu>
```

This opens and closes when the user right-clicks and all is good with the world. However, I'd like to dismiss this menu if the user presses the button as well.

I've done this before with button-click popups - if the user clicks a button to open a popup you can have an IsOpen boolean property which is set to true inside the executed command, revealing the popup.

But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way of getting to the "menu open" function on a contextmenu. At least not that I can find. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is an `IsOpen` in `ContextMenu` too.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.isopen(v=vs.110).aspx) You could bind it to a property in your ViewModel the same way you are binding the Command and have the `AddFolderCommand` set that property to false. For instance:

```
<ContextMenu IsOpen="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
```

Then in `AddFolderCommand.Execute` you can do `IsOpen = false`.

This is providing that `PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext` is actually the ViewModel you need. Note that `ContextMenu` uses its own window which prevents `DataContext` inheritance. You have several options to go around that:

- Explicity refer to another element or its `DataContext` using `ElementName` in the binding: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=other, Path=DataContext}"/>`
- Use the Parent property to access the element within which the `ContextMenu` was declared: `{Binding Path=Parent.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`
- Use a static ViewModel: `DataContext={Binding Source={x:Static local:YourStaticViewModel}`

If you don't want to do it from the ViewModel, you can use events from the code-behind: just give a name to the `ContextMenu` so you can access it from the code-behind, handle the click event on the button, and then set the `IsOpen` to false on the event handler.

Comment: Hi . Thanks for trying to help. I did spot there was an IsOpen property to bind to. The issue is that with a popup I've been opening using a button, so I have a command function in which I can set IsOpen to true. Since contextmenu is a right click, I have no idea where to bind the command function to the XAML.

Comment: @MattThrower, if I understood you correctly in this case your regard is closing and you already have a command bound to the button from where you can perform the close. You just need to set IsOpen to false from that command execute method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Visibility** property:

```
myContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```